# Create a small color box in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors

I have a `li` element. Inside the `li` element there are many elements like `input`, `labels`.

I want to put now a small color inside each `li`. The color will be provided dynamically. I want to have something square and on page load it fills with the color i provide. Is there something already existing?

Comment: You may want to post some sample html for your list with the elements it has

Comment: You want to show color picker or it it something else..?

Comment: Could we see your existing code? http://jsfiddle.net lets you paste live code examples.

Comment: Man, withou a code sample things become hard to understand. What you want to fill with the color ?? How are your `li` layout?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-color">
    <input type="text" value="Orange" />
    <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #FF850A;"></div>
    <!-- Replace "#FF850A" to change the color -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-color {
    position: relative;
}
.input-color input {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.input-color .color-box {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRyS2/1/)** for live example.

Comment: Coming in a little late to the party, is there any way to add a border to this?

Comment: Hah. That was simpler than expected. Sorry, very new to this. :)

Answer (score 18):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with CSS.

I became annoyed with nuances of CSS and not getting the look and feel quite right and figuring out different configurations of div's. I stumbled on to something much simpler (to me and hopefully others): use SVG.

Here's an example of a yellow-box:

```html
<html>
Look at me - I'm a yellow box!
<svg width="20" height="20">
<rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:#E9E612;stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
</html>
```

When used with a jinja template I can configure the fill color by supplying the correct string from python:

```
<svg width="20" height="20">
<rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:{{supplied_color_str}};stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

It's old school, but it's simple and gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, Unicode's [black square](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+2B1B) could prove useful.

```html
This is a colored box:
<span style="color: #E9E612">■</span>
```